# Insert repeated numbers mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have 100,000 rows of data in my table, all I wanted to do is to insert numbers for each row. But the thing is, I only want to insert number up to 24. In the 25th row it should again start from 1 up to 48 and so on! Can someone help me on this!

Comment: FYI people outside India probably don't know what "Lakh" means.

Comment: I also don't think you understand what "vice versa" means because your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: And why tag both SQL Server *and* MySQL?

Comment: Use NTILE(24) to divide the data into 24 ranks

Comment: Modulus operator perhaps?

Comment: I think perhaps instead of "vice versa" you mean "and so on". 
I'm trying to see a pattern in your question: The rows have to be numbered 1,2, ... , 23, 24, 1, 2, ..., 23, 24, 1, 2, ... etc.? If so, you may want to use an update statement with the modulo operator and ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: @MichaelJSwart yes

Comment: Which SQL database are you using? MySql or SQL Server? The database server will make a difference.

Comment: @MichaelJSwart it's mysql

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know (unfortunately I don't know the answer for MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the modulo/modulus operator can handle this operation for you.

```
SELECT id % 24 FROM table
```

or

```
SELECT (id % 24) + 1 FROM table
```

Since we don't have your source data you might need to add/subtract a value here to get the starting position. If you provide more data, I can update the answer to be more specific to your problem.

MySQL includes a specific `MOD()` function that accepts parameters as well if that is helpful.

```
Modulo operation. Returns the remainder of N divided by M.


mysql> SELECT MOD(234, 10);
        -> 4 
mysql> SELECT 253 % 7;
        -> 1 
mysql> SELECT MOD(29,9);
        -> 2 
mysql> SELECT 29 MOD 9;
        -> 2
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
DECLARE @size AS INT =0
DECLARE @id AS INT

WHILE (@size<100000)
BEGIN
    SET @id = ( @size % 24 ) + 1;
    INSERT INTO <table> VALUES (@id , values...) 
    SET @size = @size+1
END
```

If you want to update existing table, just use UPDATE query instead of INSERT